# How to change Picker bottom line color in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I need to change bottom line color of picker and to change the background colour of list of items displayed in the picker.I can set the background color of picker.But the background color of items in the picker by default white.Is there any custom renderer or any other solution?I add the items in picker as folllows.

The list of blood group displayed in the white color.I need to change that color.How to set items list background color?

```
public List<string> _bloodGroups = new List<string>() { "A+ve", "A-ve", "B+ve", "B-Ve", "O+ve", "O-ve", "AB+ve", "AB_ve" };

public void GetDistrictAsync()
{            
    foreach (string districts in _districts)
    {
        Picker_District.Items.Add(districts);
    }
}
```

in XAML page the code follows

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HeightRequest="10"
    Margin="20,10,20,0"  
    BackgroundColor="#91BC47">
    <Picker 
        x:Name="Picker_BloodGroup" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
        TextColor="White" 
        BackgroundColor="#91BC47">
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>Select Blood Group</x:String>                           
        </Picker.Items>
    </Picker>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no itemtemplate is exposed on the default picker, at best you can bind the text color.

Comment: @SpookKruger  Is there any custon renderers to change the items list background color

Comment: Nothing that is ready for download that I am aware of, but I am sure you can create your own =)

Comment: @SpookKruger is there any way to remove picker bottom line color? By default black color.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi @jasminemathew add this  custom renderer in xamarin ios section**
*Remember to add this line before namespace 
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]*

```
 public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    private CALayer _borderLayer;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

        var element = Element as Picker;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        //DrawBorder(element.BorderColor.ToCGColor());
        DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));

        e.NewElement.Unfocused += (sender, evt) =>
        {
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156)); // unfocused, set color

        };
        e.NewElement.Focused += (sender, evt) =>
        {
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(245, 0, 47)); ; // focused, set color
        };
    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        var element = Element as Picker;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));
    }
    public override CGRect Frame
    {
        get { return base.Frame; }
        set
        {
            base.Frame = value;

            var element = Element as Picker;
            if (element == null)
                return;

            // DrawBorder(element.BorderColor.ToCGColor());
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));
        }
    }
    private void DrawBorder(UIColor borderColor)
    {
        if (Frame.Height <= 0 || Frame.Width <= 0)
            return;

        if (_borderLayer == null)
        {
            _borderLayer = new CALayer
            {
                MasksToBounds = true,
                Frame = new CGRect(0f, Frame.Height - 1, Frame.Width, 1f),
                BorderColor = borderColor.CGColor,
                BorderWidth = 1.0f
            };

            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(_borderLayer);
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        }
        else
        {
            _borderLayer.BorderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
            _borderLayer.Frame = new CGRect(0f, Frame.Height - 1, Frame.Width, 1f);
        }
    }
}.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control != null && Element != null)
    {
        Control.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        Control.PlaceholderText = "Select";
        Control.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        Control.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        Control.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        Control.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);         
        var element = Element as BurndyRegPicker; 
        element.Title = string.Empty;?                

        element.Margin = new Xamarin.Forms.Thickness(-10, -6, -28, 4);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code is not working. SolidColorBrush() and burndyRegPicker are not in xamarin.forms.can you please tell the assembly reference?

Comment: This code needs to be used in a custom renderer for android. Badly explained answer sadly.